# Is there a way to set the encryption algorithm for certs issued by letsencrypt, as a ClusterIssuer, in microk8s?

Tags: encryption, microk8s

I'm currently have letsencrypt configured in microk8s as a ClusterIssuer and it's working fine. However, the certs are RSA2048 and I would like to use ECC384. Is there a way to do this in microk8s?

Current ClusterIssuer config is as follows:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: asdf@gmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: public
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: asdfgmail.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: public
```

Answer (score 0):

found a way to do it by creating a certificate object. i'd prefer to know how to change the default for all certs, so i don't have so create an object for each cert, but this'll do for now:

```
## https://cert-manager.io/docs/reference/api-docs/#cert-manager.io/v1.CertificatePrivateKey
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: asdf-cert
spec:
  duration: 2160h # 90d
  renewBefore: 360h # 15d
  secretName: asdf-cert
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-prod
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: asdf.org
  dnsNames:
    - asdf.org
  privateKey:
    algorithm: ECDSA
    size: 384
```